# Changing DNS records when Moving a site

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, a-record

I'm building a new Magento website on a Amazon ec2 instance and will need to point domain of their old OSCommerce site to the new ec2 instance's elastic IP address.

Normally I would have though this a simple task of updating the `A` record of their domain, but when I logged into the account with their register I see t**hey have 90 records set up already**, mostly `CNAME` & `A` records.

They have no IT guy to ask, but I'm almost 100% sure what I need to do but as I normally work with web dev stuff like php and javascript etc I just want to make sure I have it right.

To give you a **sample of their DNS records** they have set up:

```
Type    Host                            Data                        TTL      Kind    State    In Synch
A       intweb1.their-domain.com        19?.??.???.OLD              3600     Manual  Active     yes
CNAME   intweb.their-domain.com         intweb1.their-domain.com    3600     Manual  Active     yes
CNAME   www.their-domain.com            intweb1.their-domain.com    3600     Manual  Active     yes
A       fs.their-domain.com             19?.??.???.OLD              3600     Manual  Active     yes
CNAME   fileserver.their-domain.com     fs.their-domain.com         3600     Manual  Active     yes
```

I believe I only need to **REMOVE:**

```
A       intweb1.their-domain.com        19?.??.???.OLD              3600     Manual  Active     yes
```

**AND CHANGE:**

```
CNAME   www.their-domain.com            intweb1.their-domain.com    3600     Manual  Active     yes
```

**TO:**

```
A       www.their-domain.com            19?.??.???.NEW              3600     Manual  Active     yes
```

**AND ADD ANOTHER RECORD:**

```
CNAME   their-domain.com                www.their-domain.com        3600     Manual  Active     yes
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be:
Set a reasonably small ttl so if something goes wrong, you don't have to wait 1 hour to rollback (ttl is in seconds) So you avoid data written on different versions of the db depending on the clients in one site or the other (if the old site allows you to do so, you can force there a redirection to the new server to avoid this too)

- Reduce ttl to a desired amount of time for a smother change
- Change the A records to reflect the right servers IP addresses.
- Change the CNAMEs if needed to reflect the right names (if needed depending on the situation, the you exemplified should be changed, maybe you have some more)

If you are not changing the mail server nor the dns provider, just don't change MX, SOA or any related.

When you see everything is working as expected with resolution, grow the ttl to a reasonable number.

**keep in mind TTL is the most important there, if you have some nasty resolution, in your current scenario, a change will take an hour to reflect, so move it to a small number while approaching the migration date** but to a logic amount (I'm facing a migration today, and I'll set a 10' ttl for the most critical stuff, that I can face 10' for rollback, it depends on your application -have in mind that the ttl is spreaded around other dns that fwd, so you can't control resolution beyond this number-)

Comment: hadn't considered TTL.   I believe this is at the registrars default setting but I can edit it.  Although it seems to be low enogh `Min TTL 1800`, does that look ok to you?

Comment: Well, half an hour is better than an hour. In general, DNS providers limit the lowest limit if they offer dns for free (and if it's not, a low ttl generates much more requests, so you pay for that) if 1800 is the lowest you can have, is your best option. Then, the number you are putting there depends on the amount of visit and the risk to have a "split brain" between you old an new db.
Before you change your dns, copy the current values, so if for any reason you have to roll back, you avoid the time asking your old provider support about them ;)